# Is there anything I can do to prevent my iPod from crashing in iTunes after transferring songs?

Tags: ipod, crash

I've been having a problem with my iPod now for actually something like 2+ years (yes I probably should have looked into it long ago). It's a 6th generation 80GB iPod Classic.

It goes like this: I plug it in to transfer songs to it, and after transferring a limited number of tracks (around 10), iTunes and/or the iPod crashes and I need to kill the iTunes process to get it to disconnect. After this happens, my iPod will not accept any new tracks when re-plugged in, instead crashing on any attempt to transfer a new track, and to get it to work again I need to restore it to factory settings at which time it will accept another 10 or so songs before crashing. Sometimes, after the initial crash, it also wipes it's own hard drive and I lose whatever songs I did manage to transfer.

Obviously, it's a pretty low-chance case, but I can't afford a new iPod right now and this one is getting worse and worse (it used to let me put on a whole 50 songs!), so I would just like to know if there's anything *at all* I could try to make it work again (it's long out of warranty and I'm not living in a place where I have access to support).

Things I have tried: Different computers, different cables, waiting a very long time to see if it uncrashes

Answer (score 2):

If you are still having no luck after the restore try reinstalling iTunes. [Download it from the Apple website](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/) restart it, you may need to relocate your library if you have moved it from the original destination.

If nothing above works then you should try following the steps on the [Apple iPod support website](http://www.apple.com/support/ipod/five_rs/classic/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did mention in my post that I have to restore it to factory settings to make it work again. In addition I've tried downloading iTunes again and following the iPod support steps. :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: In that case it could be the harddrive. Call me synical but I have had a lot of problems with iPods over 2 years old, perhaps they are programmed to fail after the warranty period so people keep buying iPods, after all once everyone has one they are not going to sell many more. (There are a lot of iPods working outside of warranty, and I am sure this is not actually the case)

Comment: I had this exact same problem with the iPod I owned before this one after a year or so as well, so perhaps you have a point there ;)